# timeInterval update func problem. Player disappears

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

This Game:

[Game Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OakKj.jpg)

When I write this code.. Player disappears..

**Variables:**

```
var previousTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 1
var playerIsFacingRight = true
let playerSpeed = 4.0
```

**Code:**

```
extension GameScene {
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let deltaTime = currentTime - previousTimeInterval
        previousTimeInterval = currentTime

        //Player Movement
        guard let joystickKnob = joystickKnob else { return }
        let xPosition = Double(joystickKnob.position.x)
        let displacement = CGVector(dx: deltaTime * xPosition * playerSpeed, dy: 0)
        let move = SKAction.move(by: displacement, duration: 0)
        player?.run(move) 

    }
}
```

[Game Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PS0H.jpg)

Comment: post the code where you create and add you character to the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update method runs many times.

It's highly probably was disappear by soo many actions for player movement.

- You can debug inside the update and check **player?.position**
- Check the **player?.zPosition** of player, if it the same of background can position behind.
- You can use Xcode "Debug view hierarchy" to see where is the player.

Comment: I checked player?.zPosition 

 "Optional(0.0)"

Comment: please help me sir. I can share my project to you.

Comment: I sended request to you. Thanks

Comment: @Maetschl it defeats the purpose of SO by helping OP on other venues. How are others supposed to learn from that

Comment: @RonMyschuk you're right :) but I post an honest answer, with that probably he can solve the issue.